# transmission wire amp rating

Tags: wire

I have a cable which has 3 wires, each wire is 7 strands of SWG 22.

I need to find the transmission amp rating for this cable. How do I go about it?

Thanks

Comment: is there anything printed on the cable?

Comment: 665M, that is all. It is 40 year old building with old cables.

Comment: Where on this planet are you?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this table](https://www.calmont.com/wp-content/uploads/calmont-eng-wire-gauge.pdf) of a wire manufacturer 7 
strands of 22 makes a 14 gauge wire which would carry 15 amps.

That a good estimate, but remember your wire wasn’t likely manufactured by the company who published the table.